# how to read absolute positions of tap from Cirque touchpad in linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, touchpad

we have one of Cirque touchpads. 
http://www.cirque.com/downloads/docs/tsm9925.pdf

now we want to read absolute position of tap from this touchpad using c\c++ application. unfortunately company developed only windows drivers but we need to read positions in the linux. we tried to use /dev/input/eventN subsystem but received only direction of finger moving and speed of finger moving.

is it possible and how can we do this?

Comment: Touchpads rarely report absolute positions.

Comment: @relet. yes, you are right. i contacted Cirque directly and they reported that their touchpad can only tell us direction and speed and it's impossible to read absolute positions from it. thanks for all replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your supplied link:

```
For custom functionality at the product design stage, we offer software that 
allows OEMs to enable, disable or personalize advanced settings and/or 
reprogram the touch sensitive area.
```

I'd suggest contacting Cirque directly

Answer (score 1):

Touchpads rarely report absolute positions.

*Just so that you have some answer to accept ;)*

Answer (score 1):

This is how it works:

The Cirque Smart CAT (model GDU410 - this is an OLD model!) reports an 8 byte packet.
Initially the packet looks like this:

```
Byte 0, bit 0: Left button
Byte 0, bit 1: Right button
Byte 0, bit 2: Side buttons (they cannot be distinguished)
Byte 1: Relative X data
Byte 2: Relative Y data
Bytes 3-7: 0
```

To switch to absolute mode you'll have to send the following USB control requests to the device:

```
unsigned char buf[8];
do {
    Usb_Control_Request(Type=0xC1, Request=0x6A, Index=0,
        Value=0, Data Length=8, Data Buffer=buf)
} while(buf[0] & 8);
Usb_Control_Request(Type=0x41, Request=0x66, Index=0xBB, Value=1, No data)
do { ... /* C1/6A, see above */ } while(buf[0] & 8);
Usb_Control_Request(Type=0x41, Request=0x66, Index=0xB5, Value=0x3E0, No data)
do { ... /* C1/6A */ } while(buf[0] & 8);
Usb_Control_Request(Type=0x41, Request=0x66, Index=0xA2, Value=0xFEE, No data)
do { ... /* C1/6A */ } while(buf[0] & 8);
Usb_Control_Request(Type=0x41, Request=0x66, Index=0xB4, Value=0xE, No data)
do { ... /* C1/6A */ } while(buf[0] & 8);
Usb_Control_Request(Type=0x41, Request=0x64, Index=0, Value=0, No data)
do { ... /* C1/6A */ } while(buf[0] & 8);
```

Maybe under Linux this can be done using "libusb". Although I already did some driver development under Linux I did not use "libusb", yet.

After doing this the 8-byte packets look like this:

```
Byte 0: Buttons, as before
Bytes 1-3: 0
Byte 4: low 8 bits of X finger position
Byte 5: bits 0-2: high 3 bits of X finger position
        bits 3-7: low 5 bits of Y finger position
Byte 6: bits 0-5: high 6 bits of Y finger position
Byte 7, low 7 (?) bits: non-zero if finger touches pad, 0 if not
        some pads report the finger pressure;
        MAYBE this is done in this field.

Finger positions:
X position: left ~0x790, right ~0x70
Y position: top ~0, bottom ~0x5B0
```

The device driver provided by Cirque uses the absolute position mode to perform scrolling and similar functions that depend on the absolute finger position.